# RecyclerView with 2 columns. How set space between them?

Tags: android

Fragment set recyclerView columns number:

```
sortRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        sortRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
```

Here layout that content recyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/sortRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here item layout in recyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/place_holder_color">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/preview_image_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here result:

[image: rv]

I need next:

1. Set 20dp on the left and right side
2. set 10 dp between 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

You can set something like this:
 - for the 1'st ImageView:

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
```

- for the 2'nd ImageView:

  android:paddingLeft="5dp"

  android:paddingRight="10dp"

Comment: No second image. I update my post. It's a second column.

Comment: I don't get it @Alex

Comment: I have recyclerView with 2 columns. On every column show only ONE ImageView "@+id/imageViewPhoto"

Comment: Ah, and the above is the code you're using for your items, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Comment: Then I would set the recyclerView's attribute to: android:paddingLeft="15dp" and android:paddingRight="15dp", and for items (ConstraintLayout), android:paddingLeft="5dp" and android:paddingRight="5dp", or margin, which suits your need better. Try this and let me know.

Comment: It's not good because scrollBar shift to left (15dp)

Comment: Then just don't set padding right for the recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

add to the one on the left:

`android:marginRight="5dp"`

`android:marginLeft="20dp"`

add to the one on the right:

`android:marginLeft="5dp"`

`android:marginRight="20dp"`

Comment: No two images. I have recyclerView with 2 columns. On every column show only ONE ImageView "@+id/imageViewPhoto"

Comment: add that code to the parent layout and I suggest you work with `Relative layout`

Comment: I found solution. I must extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration and override method getItemOffsets()